# "submitting" the form for a username and text for a chatbox doesn't seem to actually submit anything

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created a form for a username and a text message but right now pressing submit doesn't actually submit anything despite it being close to the code for my login and registration form wich do properly work.
the code:

```
<form id="myChatForm">
<input type= "text" placeholder= "Enter a name" name= "user_name" id= "user_name"><br>
<textarea placeholder= "type your message" name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="3"></textarea><br>
<button type= "submit" name= "submit" value= "submit" class= "btn btn-succes btn-lg" id = "sendMessageBtn"> Send Message</button><br>
</form>
<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
   if (isset($_POST['user_name'])) {
       $uname = ($_POST['user_name']);
    }
   if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
       $umessage = ($_POST['message']);
   }

   $query = "INSERT INTO chatroom (name, message) VALUES ('$uname', '$umessage')"; 
   $run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
   }
   ?>
```

For as far as I know, the problem lies with the form because before I had

```
if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && isset($_POST['message'])){
```

I would get errors saying that user_name and message were both undifined.

Comment: you're leaving yourself wide open to an serious sql injection here. Use a prepared statement if you value your work.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form id="myChatForm" method="POST" action="**??**">
...
</form
```

Try setting forms 'method' to POST, and setting the 'action' to where you want the form to POST the values to.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have a misunderstanding on how HTML forms work.

The web page that contains the form and the web page that gets the form input and acts on it are not the same page/file. Your form web page points to your form action web page by using the `action` attribute.

You can put them both on the same HTML file, but I suggest you gain a good understanding on how HTML forms work with the classic "two separate files" design first before complicating things further.

Comment: I actually have the php/mysql part in a different file but I simply posted the important parts under each other

Comment: You are still missing the `action` and `method` attributes in your `form` tag.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the form's method is a GET.
Either you access your fields using $_GET or change your form's method to POST

```
<form id="myChatForm" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add method to your form `method="post"`, you search vars in `$_POST[""]`, but sends by default - `GET`, so write:

```
<form id="myChatForm" method="post">
```